# Controll pathway when going through links

Tags: css, codeigniter, url, redirect

If the title is not clear, ill make up for it here.

So I have a log in page that is loaded in the `index()` function of a controller that I routed in the routes config as default controller.

So when I go to localhost then click on the(lets say the folder is Final)

the log in page would be displayed with the address/path of localhost/Final/

Then I attached a css on that page using  tag or an anchor() tag.

say I have a sign up option on that log in page after I successfully singed up I get a link back to log in,

so from the sign up page i get the address of `localhost/Finals/index.php/login/create_account`

```
login = controller, create_account= function
```

after which I get redirected to a success page which has the same address with sign up.

Then there will be a link back to log in page.

now the problem arises, the address is now

`localhost/Finals/index.php/login`

So my css tag on the indexed login page was just css/default.css

so when i get to that login page after signing up the css link cant be found because of the difference in the path. since it moved up 1 path ahead,

now I have to change my css link to ../css/default.css for it to work on that login(not called via index)

The same also happens on my pagination, first load from the controller it loads the css perfectly, when i click on the links() 1 2 3 .... the css then cannot be found because yet again the url changes. I used uri segment for offset.

I am currently reading this ci helper guide on url

Solutions would be that I dynamically assign my css link or my URL.

I still have to solve the other problem I have with pagination and table which doesn't show.(refer to my other question).

Comment: After signing up should i just call the index function?

Comment: Login CSS problem solved, used  <?php echo redirect('', 'refresh');?> </p>

Still css problem with pagination links though because of uri segments used as an offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `base_url` from [URL Helper Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) like:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>YOUR_CSS_FOLDER/YOUR_CSS_FOLDER" >
```

OR

You can use:

```
<base href="<?= base_url(); ?>"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="YOUR_CSS_FOLDER/YOUR_CSS_FOLDER">
```

Comment: I will try this, i just solved my login css problem though, instead of using anchor or a tag

i used redirect

My signup_successful page now contains only this,

 <?php echo redirect('', 'refresh');?> </p>

it is empty, since my base url is localhost/final/

so it directed me to that address which showed my login perfectly with css. :) yay to me